# Transfer files directly between computers over ethernet cable?

Tags: networking

I often need to transfer files over my home network between computers and have found that WiFi transfers really aren't the best idea. (facepalm) If I have a CAT-5, 5e, or 6 cable lying around, how can I connect one computer directly to the other with it? If a SSH server is running on `server` and I connect `client` to server using a CAT-5 cable directly between the two, can I then use SSH to transfer files? What do I need to do in order to set something like this up? Is a router required?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If at least one computer's network card supports auto-crossover, you can connect both with a direct cable. (Auto-crossover, also called "auto-MDIX", is part of the Gigabit Ethernet standard, but is very often supported by 100 Mbps cards too.) Otherwise, you'll need either a cross-over cable, a hub, or a switch.

After setting up the physical connection, configure networking in the OS:

- If both ends have **IPv6**, you can just connect using the other computer's **[link-local address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address)**; for example, **`ssh fe80::4a5d:60ff:fee8:658f%eth0`**. (On Linux, the string after `%` is your Ethernet card's name, while Windows uses the numeric interface ID from `netsh interface ipv6 show interface`.)

  You can also add shorter addresses manually, such as `fc00::1` and `fc00::2` (from the [`fc00::/7` network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_local_address)).
- For **IPv4-only** hosts, **manually assign IP addresses** from the same subnet – for example, `10.0.0.1/8` and `10.0.0.2/8`.

  Some operating systems will automatically assign link-local IPv4 addresses in the `169.254.0.0/16` range.

Comment: An update: just transferred a file at 70 megabytes per second for the win.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you use an [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) server on one of the machines to avoid the encryption processing of ssh which might give you faster throughput, especially on low-speed CPUs:

On the "server" machine, create yourself an rsyncd.conf file containing something like:

```
[download]
comment =       Storage general files
path =          /home/user/Download
read only =     false
write only =    false
list =          true
incoming chmod = Du=rwx,go=rx,Fu=rw,go=r
uid =           user
gid =           user
```

Then fire up rsync in "server" mode:

```
sudo rsync --daemon --config=rsyncd.conf  --no-detach --log-file=/dev/tty
```

Then on the client, to receive:

```
rsync rsync://host/download/file-name local-file-name
```

or to send:

```
rsync local-file-name rsync://host/download/file-name
```

When you've finished, just CTRL-C the server process.

Comment: Very easy to follow solution. Thanks and +1 from me. I find doing all the samba, nfs and whatnot to tedious for a simply file transfer. Also nice tip for the exclusion of the encryption process!

Comment: @rbaleksandar: Thanks. Now that I have gigabit ethernet at home, I find I can generally exceed 100MB/sec with this technique whereas scp or rsync over ssh tends to max out at 20-40MB/sec. An even simpler technique is to use `netcat` (nc) directly on both machines.

Comment: Will give it a shot. And yeah, the speed is really nice. Just transferred a an ISO of like 8GB in no time. :3

Answer (score 1):

The short version of it is:

- If at least one of the computers has a gigabit interface, or one supports MDI/MDX no router is required. Plug in a plain CAT5E or better cable.
- Of both have 10/100mbit cards use a cross-cable or two regular cables and a switch.

Next configure both computers to be in the same subnet and set up routing. (See  this on our sister site: [how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work](http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work) for the background).

You did not mention which OS you are using, but assuming a unix like:

- Computer 1:  ifconfig em0 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 (replace em0 with the name of the interface).
- Computer 2: ifconfig em0 192.168.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.0
  Both network cards are now configured in for the same LAN.
- Your OS is likely to 'automagically' add routes to the local network. If not use `route add -net 192.168.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1` on computer 1. Do the same on computer 2 with `route add -net 192.168.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.2`

Test the connection with ping or copy with scp.

(Client:~homedir> `scp myfile 192.1.68.0.2:Destination_folder`)

Comment: I don't seem to get an automatically added route (Xubuntu 14.04) - after setting the IPs, trying to ssh to the other computer gives me "ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.2 port 22: No route to host".  And using your route add command gives me the Usage info for route, so presumably there's something wrong with the syntax.

Comment: It haws been a while since I posted it and I do not recall if I tested this in a VM with Linux or on FreeBSd.  Will check when I am home with both OS's and add working syntax for both.

Answer (score 0):

You will either have to set up a bridge on server (S) with the usual network and then connect the client (C) to said network (IP-wise) or use a custom subnet. The latter is pretty straightforward (with eth0 being the connected interfaces on the client and server):

```
C # ip addr add 10.0.1.2/24 dev eth0
S # ip addr add 10.0.1.1/24 dev eth0
```

at this point, `C # ping 10.0.1.1` should work. If the SSH server on S is configured to listen on all interfaces (i.e. `0.0.0.0`), you should be ready to go, otherwise you will have to make it listen there (by adapting `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`).

If you don't get the speeds you expect, make sure (via `ethtool eth0`) that the connection speed has been detected properly. You can change it using the same tool.