# Improve speed between two PCs on Wifi by directly connecting with single Ethernet cable

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, home-networking

I have a wifi network at home with multiple devices connected for internet and also for filesharing with SMB. Two PCs on the network are physically very close to each other. Is it possible to directly connect these two PCs to each other with a single ethernet cable to improve the transfer speeds between them?

Do I need to create a subnet or do some kind of bridging? One PC is running Ubuntu and the other I dual boot with both Ubuntu and Windows 10 occasionally.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this. You will need to manually define IPs for the etherenet interface (because there is no DHCP available for the interview). These IPs need to be in a different subnet to everything else. (If your wifi uses 192.168x.x, try using 10.x.x.x)

That said, from a useability POV, it's probably simpler and faster to use a router as an AP client and bridge the 2 PC's to 2 of its ethernet ports, for a seem less network. You do need to make sure the router/AP can handle the required packets per second between Ethernet devices though.

Comment: would it be worth adding that he should not set a gateway for this cable network?

Answer (score 0):

This should answer your question: [Transfer files directly between computers over ethernet cable?](https://superuser.com/questions/510508/transfer-files-directly-between-computers-over-ethernet-cable?rq=1)
I did get my laptop (that had wifi) to give a Desktop internet by a 1-1 Ethernet connection by bridging the Ethernet adapter and the wifi adapter or my laptop(Win8.1).